# always run a middleware in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

i want an expressjs middlware to be executed always. 
That is even if there is an error in the next() or not.

is it possible?

example

```
app.get('/',[middle1,middle2],doIt)
```

the middle2 should always execute even if the middle1 executes next with error.

NOTE: the middle2 should always execute last and takes the values calculated by the previous middlewares. also there are lot of middlewares between middle1 and middle2.

Comment: Schedule your middle2 function after middle1, and you can achieve this by [try... finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/4yahc5d8(v=vs.94).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `middle1` is known to not use any async operations from which it calls next(), then you can wrap it and put a try/catch around it so that if it throws, you can just call `next()` on its behalf.

If it does use async operations or you don't know if it will use async operations, then you will only catch its exceptions if it throws synchronously (before it goes async) and you will not be able to catch any exceptions that it throws asynchronously.  About the best you could do for async behavior is to set some sort of timeout in your wrapper.  If it hasn't called `next()` within some period of time (either because it threw an exception or just failed in some other weay), then you call next after the timeout period.

Wrapping a non-async `middle1` could look like this:

```
function wrap(fn) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        var nextCalled = false;
        try {
            fn(req, res, function() {
                nextCalled = true;
                next();
            });
        } finally {
            if (!nextCalled) {
                next();
            }
        }
    }
}

app.get('/',[wrap(middle1),middle2],doIt);
```

The `wrap()` function inserts a stub as the middleware function.  That stud inserts its own `next()` function so it can tell if the actual middleware function calls `next()` or not.  It then wraps an exception handler around the middleware function so if it throws an exception synchronously, then it can recover.  After the function returns, it checks to see if `next()` was called and, if not, it calls it.

As explained earlier this approach only works if the middleware function is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but i have more than 2 middleware async functions in the route. even if it throws error in next i need the last middleware to be always executed and no i cant move this middleware to the first coz i'm using the results from the other middleware in this last middleware.

Comment: i think the only way o handle this is to not throw the errors in next but in a variable in side req object.??

Comment: @NisanthSojan - Is this your own middleware?  If so, just make it so it doesn't throw or that it catches it's own exceptions.  If not, why is it throwing?  You must have something wrong if it's throwing.  Basically throwing in middleware is bad if you don't want to abort the request.  It should be avoided by either making the middleware bulletproof against throwing or by pre-flighting whatever the middleware throws about and avoiding the middleware if it's just going to throw.

Comment: by throwing i meant executing next() with error as first parameter. Oops sorry my bad :)

Comment: @NisanthSojan - then please fix your question because everything written so far assumes that "throw" means "throwing an exception" which is how pretty much everyone would interpret what you wrote.

Comment: the question is now more clearer. Also i have fixed the issue by not giving error in next but by saving it in req object and processing it in the other middlewares.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not care about the order of execution, you can simply have function middle2 execute inside app.use.

```
app.use(middle2);

app.get('/pathx, middle1, middle3, doIt);
```

middle2 will always be executed on every request.  However, middle2 will execute before any of the other middleware

If you require middle2 to execute last in sequence, then a simple modification using the async module should accomplish what you want

```
async = require('async');

function middleware(req, res, next){
    var functionList = [middle1, middle3];

    async.series(functionList, function(err, results){
        if(err){
            middle2(req, res, next);
            next(err);
        }

        middle2(req, res, next);
        next();
    }
}


app.get('/pathX', middleware, doIt);
```